# How to replace custom post type slug with an ACF value?

Tags: custom-post-types, advanced-custom-fields

I have a drop down select type field in Advanced Custom Fields. The values are Video and Image.

I want to replace the Custom post type slug. Currently, it is video.

I want to change mysite.com/video/post-name to mysite.com/1/post-name or mysite.com/0/post-name

I mean when the drop down value Video is selected, it will show mysite.com/1/post-name.

I can replace the post type slug.

```
function update_video_slug( $args, $post_type) {

$cptslug = "newslug";

if ( 'video' === $post_type ) {
    $args['rewrite']['slug'] = $cptslug;
}

return $args;

}

add_filter( 'register_post_type_args', 'update_video_slug', 10, 2 );
```

Can be the $cptslug value dynamic according to ACF value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can be the `$cptslug` value dynamic according to ACF value?

Yes, it can.

Here's how:

1. First off, my ACF field settings are as follows:

   Name: `video_or_image`
   Type: Select
   Options:

   ```
   1 : Video
   0 : Image
   ```
2. So I register the post type like so, where the rewrite slug is set to `%video_or_image%` — i.e. `%{Name of the ACF field}%`, but you *don't* have to follow that format:

   ```
   register_post_type( 'video', array(
       'label'   => 'Video',
       'public'  => true,
       'rewrite' => array(
           'slug' => '%video_or_image%',
       ),
       ...
   ) );
   ```

   *Or if you want to or can only use the `register_post_type_args` to change the rewrite slug,* then just set the `$cptslug` to `%video_or_image%`.
3. Next, I register the rewrite tag (`%video_or_image%`) after the `register_post_type()` call, which is hooked to the `init` action:

   ```
   add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', '([^/]+)' );
   ```

   *Registering the tag is mandatory*, and ensures that the tag is *properly replaced* with the RegEx pattern (i.e. `([^/]+)`) when the rewrite rules are saved:
4. Then I replace the rewrite tag with the proper (ACF) field *value* using the `post_type_link` filter:

   ```
   add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $url, $post ){
       if ( 'video' === $post->post_type ) {
           $value = get_field( 'video_or_image', $post->ID );
           $url = str_replace( '%video_or_image%', $value, $url );
       }

       return $url;
   }, 10, 2 );
   ```

That's all, but don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — simply visit the permalink settings page.

And I suggest you to set a default value for your ACF field<strike>, and use "better" values if possible.. I mean, other than `1` or `0`.. but if you're sure about such values, then (I think) it's alright</strike>. =)

### UPDATE

In my case, using only `([^/]+)` in the rewrite tag, causes troubles when loading Pages (i.e. `page` post type):

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', '([^/]+)' );
```

**How I solved the problem**

1. Use a unique identifier, e.g. `v/` as in:

   ```
   add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', 'v/([^/]+)' );
   ```

   Then in the post permalink, `v/` should also be added to the rewrite tag replacement value — see step #4 above:

   ```
   $url = str_replace( '%video_or_image%', 'v/' . $value, $url );
   ```
2. I restricted the ACF field value to numeric, then I used:

   ```
   add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', '(\d+)' );
   ```

   That `(\d+)` does not guarantee no conflict with other rewrite rules, but at least in my case, it worked.

Sorry about the `([^/]+)` — I thought the `0` and `1` values were just examples. I should've just used `(\d+)`.

Comment: Awesome. But when I make CPT using CPT UI plugin, it seems not working.

Comment: One more thing. I checked lately the CPT posts show 404 error. FYI, I have refeshed and saved the permalink page.

Comment: Have you registered the proper *rewrite tag*? (I updated answer and removed my previous comment)

Comment: Those rewrite rules will also capture `parent/child/` page requests.

Comment: Yes, @Milo, I'm aware of that. Hence I suggested the unique identifier.

Comment: @Noobie, answer updated. The unique identifier in the rewrite tag/replacement should fix the 404 error. And thank you Milo - if you notice other issues, do let me know. (Lately, I often make silly mistakes...)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I didn't add the add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', '([^/]+)' ); Now all is working fine, apparently. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome, @Noobie. But I updated the answer - the "UPDATE" part might help you and/or someone else. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ, me again. Adding add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', '([^/]+)' ); causes redirection for all the pages to the home page. I have added the code like this: add_action('init', 'add_my_rewrites');
function add_my_rewrites() {
 add_rewrite_tag( '%video_or_image%', '([^/]+)' );
    }

Comment: You should then use a *unique identifer*, or if the value of the ACF field is numeric, you can try `(\d+)` instead of the `([^/]+)`. Refer to the "UPDATE" part in the answer.

Comment: Perfect! Seems all settled after using (\d+) as the ACF values are numeric. Cool.

Comment: Awesome, @Noobie. :)

Comment: Hi @SallyCJ, me again with an almost similar problem. I have a taxonomy slug articles_tags, I want to remove it from URL. How can I do it?

Comment: @Noobie, not sure if I fully understand that, but you should post a new question and not asking here. :)

Comment: It doesn't work with custom field suite plugin. Any ideas?

Comment: @chithra, I'd love to help, but you should post another question with the code you've attempted.. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ I used get_post_meta and it fixed the issue. I need to set pages with unique identifier like mysite.com/v. Is this possible? I tried to set this, but it gives 404.

Comment: @SallyCJ I've added it as a separate question - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/362784/how-to-replace-custom-post-type-slug-with-custom-field-value-by-maintaining-a-sp