# How to replace custom post type slug with custom field value by maintaining a specific URL structure?

Tags: custom-post-types

I want to replace a custom post type slug with custom field value.

I've used the below code for that:

```
add_rewrite_tag( '%employeetype%', 'our-team/([^/]+)' );
add_filter( 'post_type_link', function( $url, $post ){
    if ( 'developer' === $post->post_type ) {
        $customSlug = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'employee_type', TRUE ) ? get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'employee_type', TRUE ) : 'developers'; // can be two vales develeopers and staff
        $url = str_replace( '%employeetype%', 'our-team/'.$customSlug, $url );
    }
    return $url;
}, 10, 2 );
```

I also want to maintain the below pages:
mysite.com/our-team/ 
mysite.com/our-team/developers - this page redirects to index page
mysite.com/our-team/staff - this page redirects to index page
mysite.com/our-team/developers/abcd (achieved with above code) works fine

Can we do anything here to achieve this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed this issue by adding the below code:

```
add_rewrite_rule('our-team/developers/?$','index.php?pagename=our-team/developers', 'top');
add_rewrite_rule('our-team/support-staff/?$','index.php?pagename=our-team/support-staff', 'top');
```

Comment: You can actually do it with a single call to `add_rewrite_rule()`: `add_rewrite_rule('our-team/(developers|support-staff)/?$','index.php?pagename=our-team/$matches[1]', 'top');` It will save some database space. :)

Comment: Awesome :) @SallyCJ